# Projectile Motion | Modify results so the projectile peak would be constant with other trials

Tags: kinematics, projectile

**Context**

Imagine, for my experiment I throw a basketball up and forward, creating a parabolic shape. Let's say that I know I applied **2 N (force)**, the peak of the parabolic shape from the ground is **1 m (height)**, it has **3 m/s (final velocity)** and it landed **5 m (distance)** away from me. (note: I just made up the values)

Now imagine that I throw the basketball multiple times, each time I obviously would get different value since I, as a human being, cannot control my force to be constant.

My question is: if I want let's say the **height** to be the same for all my trials, let's say I want the **(new) height = 2 m**, is it okay to:

```
the_rate = new_height / old_heigt = 2 m / 1 m = 2  <-- the rate how much I need to modify the data

new_force = old_force * the_rate = 2 N * 2 = 4 N

new_distance = old_distance * the_rate = 5 m * 2 = 10 m

new_velocity = old_velocity * the_rate = 3 m/s * 2 = 6 m/s
```

so at the end I would have this:

```
old_height    =  1 m   |   new_height    =   2 m
old_force     =  2 N   |   new_force     =   4 N
old_distance  =  5 m   |   new_distance  =  10 m
```

Does that work? Is that ok? Is it wrong?

Comment: So, you are basically asking if (e.g.) doubling the height would also double all other variables (force, throwing distance, final velocity)? If so, it would be helpful to write down the equation of motion for this system and just calculate these values to see how they depend on each other.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned above, it is helpful to write down the equation of motion for this case. This is then the equation that describes how all parameters depend on each other.

It should be noted that the relevant parameter here is the initial velocity, not the force. Only the velocity (including the angle) when the ball leaves the hand is relevant, not how it was accelerated to that velocity. We also only look at the case when the ball is thrown from ground level.

From this we get expressions for the maximum height $h$
$$h = \frac{v_0^2}{2g}\sin^2(\alpha)$$
and the maximum distance $d$
$$d = \frac{v_0^2}{g}\sin^2(\alpha).$$
By symmetry, the initial and final velocity are equal. (You can think of the ball being thrown in the opposite direction - the trajectory would look the same.)

As you can see, both depend quadratically on the initial velocity $v_0$. **Hence, doubling the height also double sthe maximum distance, while the initial velocity only increases by a factor of $\sqrt 2$.**